# Mustache. X amount of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mustache

I currently have this mustache code:

```
 $.getJSON('data.json', function(data1) {
        intro1_template =  "{{#topic.subTopics.0}}   <h2>{{subTopicTitle}}</h2>       {{/topic.subTopics.0}}";
        html = Mustache.to_html(intro1_template, data1);
        $('.intro1_template_container').html(html);

        intro2_template =  "{{#topic.subTopics.1}}   <h2>{{subTopicTitle}}</h2>   {{/topic.subTopics.1}}";
        html = Mustache.to_html(intro2_template, data1);
        $('.intro2_template_container').html(html);

        intro3_template =  "{{#topic.subTopics.2}}   <h2>{{subTopicTitle}}</h2>   {{/topic.subTopics.2}}";
        html = Mustache.to_html(intro3_template, data1);
        $('.intro3_template_container').html(html);
    });
```

This obviously puts 3 separate pieces of information into 3 separate divs.

However, is possible to create X amount of divs based on the length of `topic.Subtopics`?

For example. If there are 10 instances of `topic.subTopics` then there would be 10 divs each with a different `topic.subTopics` in it

I think it would be something like this. Where `X` is all of the `topic.subTopics` and each time a new div with class `intro_template_container` is created with the next `topic.subTopics` item in it

```
 $.getJSON('data.json', function(data1) {
        intro_template =  "{{#topic.subTopics.X}}   <h2>{{subTopicTitle}}</h2>       {{/topic.subTopics.X}}";
        html = Mustache.to_html(intro1_template, data1);
        $('.intro1_template_container').html(html);

    });
```

Comment: Something like this: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#non-empty-lists ?

Comment: But isn't this one template which goes into one div. I would like the template to create multiple instances of the div each with a different item

Comment: It would look like this http://i57.tinypic.com/2rge2qf.png

Comment: Aren't these `.introx_template_container` divs located next to each other? It was not clear. Then why don't you write a simple loop?